# Custom objectMode Writable stream that writes data upon a condition

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a custom Node js Writable stream with objectMode that only writes objects to some sink only if the internal buffer has objects equal to highWaterMark or when stream.end() is called.  How can I do that?
Obviously, I can't put the condition inside _write() or _writev().  Where should I place the condition?